# Replace val() from access to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I have my function val() which i use on Access to get a group by number.

I explain :  in my group by with val **17 18 19 110 11 112 113** 
And without : 
**11 110 111 [..] 119 12 13 14**

here is my line val(mid(myData,2,2)))
I would like to found how to get the same result on Oracle, where val() is not present.

i tried translate and regexp_instr but without success.

Comment: I don't understand your question as explained, but `val(mid(myData,2,2))` in Oracle is `TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(myData, 2, 2))`. Hope this helps.

Comment: It is what i wanted :) 
Thanks for your help !